# How to send a file in request node-fetch or Node?

Tags: node.js, file, post, node-fetch

How do I attach a file in Node or Node Fetch POST request? I am trying to invoke an API which will import a CSV or XLS file. Is this possible using Node or Node Fetch?

Comment: just to be clear: you want to create an endpoint which will accept file as input and store / process it on your nodejs server using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) ?

Comment: Hmm here is my understanding of the question: it does not involve a nodejs server. They want to POST a file to a service (which service is not important) using `node-fetch` from within a nodejs program (so that program would be an http client from that perspective. It could also be a server for other purposes but that is irrelevant).

Answer (score 73):

[`README.md`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/1.x/README.md) says:

> Use native stream for body, on both request and response.

And [sources indicate it supports several types](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/v2.0.0-alpha.5/src/body.js#L31-L43), like `Stream`, `Buffer`, `Blob`... and also will try to coerce as `String` for other types.

Below snippet shows 3 examples, all work, with v1.7.1 or 2.0.0-alpha5 (see also other example further down with `FormData`):

```
let fetch = require('node-fetch');
let fs = require('fs');

const stats = fs.statSync("foo.txt");
const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;

// You can pass any of the 3 objects below as body
let readStream = fs.createReadStream('foo.txt');
//var stringContent = fs.readFileSync('foo.txt', 'utf8');
//var bufferContent = fs.readFileSync('foo.txt');

fetch('http://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-length": fileSizeInBytes
    },
    body: readStream // Here, stringContent or bufferContent would also work
})
.then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Here is `foo.txt`:

```
hello world!
how do you do?
```

Note: `http://httpbin.org/post` replies with JSON that contains details on request that was sent.

Result:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "hello world!\nhow do you do?\n", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "28", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "86.247.18.156", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

If you need to send a file as part of a form with more parameters, you can try:

- `npm install form-data`
- pass a `FormData` object as body (`FormData` is a kind of `Stream`, via [`CombinedStream`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/blob/master/lib/form_data.js#L34) [library](https://github.com/felixge/node-combined-stream))
- do not pass `header` in the options (unlike examples above)

and then this works:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream('foo.txt'));
formData.append('blah', 42);
fetch('http://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
```

Result (just showing what is sent):

```
----------------------------802616704485543852140629
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

hello world!
how do you do?

----------------------------802616704485543852140629
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blah"

42
----------------------------802616704485543852140629--
```

Comment: Is there way of forming the above structure without using form-data module, that can be then consumed by the node-fetch body parameter?

Comment: @Avinash You would have to implement [the spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) ‍♂️. If your input is not arbitrarily complex, it might be straightforward. [Here](https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-multipart) is an easier to read explanation.

Comment: @HuguesM. How did 'filename="foo.txt" get into the body?  I only see the data being added.

Comment: How would you fetch the multipart portion from an incoming request object?

Comment: wouldn't this send the stream object instead of the content of the file, i used readFileSync instead

Answer (score 46):

I was looking for how to use `node-fetch` to upload files via `multipart/form-data` and [their GitHub docs actually shows how to do this](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch#post-with-form-data-detect-multipart). Below is modified example showing how to attach a buffer to `FormData` and upload that.

```
const FormData = require('form-data');     
const form = new FormData();

const buffer = // e.g. `fs.readFileSync('./fileLocation');
const fileName = 'test.txt';

form.append('file', buffer, {
  contentType: 'text/plain',
  name: 'file',
  filename: fileName,
});

fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', { method: 'POST', body: form })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Sharing this for anyone else who googled "node-fetch upload file multipart" like I did.

Comment: Nice thanks @rico-kahler, I've removed my down vote. Note to others, personally wouldn't ever use a buffer or read files synchronously, since large files will exceed RAM and take a significant amount of time to read. Unfortunately that form-data package doesn't seem to work well with streams, I think the issue is caused by the lack of a content length in the request header and content length is somewhat complex to calculate.

Comment: It works for me, but instead of append('file') need to add append('upload')

Comment: the above request doesn't work if we want to send the request with headers. Could you show how to send it with headers?

Comment: @ChandaraChea add headers to the fetch API options: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#fetch-options e.g. `fetch('/blah', { headers: { /* ... */} })`

Comment: passing the contentType, name and fileName options are what made the API I was POSting to accept the file. Thank you!