# Curl -F POST request translation

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, npm-request

What would be the HTTP equivalent of this cURL request? I've tried to translate and haven't been able to pass the file correctly to the API.

```
$ curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://xxxxxx
```

I've tried:

```
const formData = {
  file: 'pathToFile'
}

request
  .post({
    url: 'xxxxxx',
    form: formData
  })
  .on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

which gives me a 5xx server error ~ file param undefined.

how would I go about doing this in Node.js? I'm using [Request](https://github.com/request/request)

Answer (score 0):

[Doc](https://github.com/request/request#forms) says to use `fs.createReadStream(...)` to pass a file:

```
var formData = {
  my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test.txt'),
};
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Also the option is `formData`, not `form`. Unless we are speaking of different versions.

Alternatively, there is also [node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44021538/6730571).