# How do I send a file as form data binary, with node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fetch, restify

**Intro:**

> As of Feb 11th 2020, `request` is fully deprecated. No new changes are
>   expected to land. In fact, none have landed for some time. This
>   package is also deprecated because it depends on request.
>    - https://github.com/request/request-promise

I have been using npm `request-promise` for sending files from node backend to `restify` endpoints. Unfortunately `request-promise` is being deprecated so I am switching to `node-fetch` instead.

with request-promise I was able to construct a request something like this:

```
const formData = {
  file: {
    value: file,
    options: {
      filename: 'someFileName.xlsx',
      contentType: 'image/jpg'
    }
  }
}
const requestOptions = { ...., formData };
return requestPromiseFetch(url, requestOptions).then(response => { ....});
```

And get the file from the request under "files" `req.files.file.path`

This also works when getting files from browser fetch, which in chrome network request looks like this:

[image]

```
"postData": {
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryE6T9nfRvBAScnlki",
    "text": "------WebKitFormBoundaryE6T9nfRvBAScnlki\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"importTest.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryE6T9nfRvBAScnlki--\r\n",
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "file",
        "value": "(binary)"
      }
    ]
  }
```

On the backend I nicely receive the file from the browser request like this:

```
async function receivingFile (req) {
  console.log(req.files);
  const result = await schema.importer.importingFile({ fullPath: req.files.file.path });
  return { result };
}
```

console.log prints:

```
{
  file: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 4803,
    path: '/var/folders/jv/py0twd4d2dgfslwry_ch8_tm0000gp/T/upload_3ba513d3d1ee5912c1d20067c3775c47.xlsx',
    name: 'importTest.xlsx',
    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2020-05-05T11:18:24.421Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: '/var/folders/jv/py0twd4d2dgfslwry_ch8_tm0000gp/T/upload_3ba513d3d1ee5912c1d20067c3775c47.xlsx',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 4803,
      closed: true
    }
  }
}
```

I wan't the received request made by `node-fetch` to look the same, so that I can get the file just like I get it when it is sent by the browser fetch, and as used to be when sent by `request-promise`

I have been reading through this question: [How to send a file in request node-fetch or Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021538/how-to-send-a-file-in-request-node-fetch-or-node)
But none of the answers helped me produce the same result as I was able to when using `request-promise` to construct the http request.